# Show notice bar on every screen

Tags: react-native

I'm using react native to build an app and I need to show a notice bar on every screen. The notice needs to be placed on top of the screen. The bar displays internet connection.

I'm using react native navigation but I don't know how to stick the notice bar before every screen rendering.

How can I stick the notice bar on the top of every screen in my app ?
Thanks.

Comment: you can use `header` prop in react navigation